# Regression: fixed effects vs. random effects vs. first differences?

Tags: regression, econometrics, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I'm learning econometrics and I'm stumped with a textbook problem.

Use the [JTRAIN dataset](http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/data/wooldridge/jtrain.des) (which provides information on manufacturing plants in Michigan from the years: 1987, 1988 and 1989) to determine the effect of the job training grant on hours of job training per employee.

I'm estimating the model using three methods (FE, FD, and RE)

The estimation results are the following:

Fixed Effects:
[image: FE]

Random Effects:
[image: RE]

First Differences:
[image: FD]

How would I go about knowing which of the three methods is the best one to use (in this case)?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In most of the cases, one should go for fixed effects regression, as omitted
variables pose a substantial threat in making causal inferences. Panel data and fixed effects help us to deal time-invariant omitted variables.
What you essentially do with fixed effects is “within transformation” as it
demeans all variables within their group, in your case manufacturing plants.
In random effects model, you assume that unnobserved heterogeneity, and your independent variables are uncorrelated which is a strong assumption. 
First differencing is another way removing unobserved heterogeneities but this time by subtracting the lagged observation rather than group mean. If your N
is small, T is large, you can go for first differences. In your case, I would go for both FE and FD and do not bother with RE.

Comment: Does the source of the variation in grants matter for the choice of estimator? If grants were given out by lottery, would you still recommend FE/FD? What if workers applied from grants instead and they were awarded by merit or need?

Comment: Well I don't think my answer is good for this particular question -- It is hard to talk about causal inference here in any case because probably grants are not randomly assigned -- so any of FE, FD or RE will not help. In case of random assignment, you can simply take a look at sample differences assuming treatment and control samples are balanced

Comment: I believe this dataset was put together by Jeff Wooldridge and came originally from [this paper](Holzer, Block, Cheatham, and Knott )(https://doi.org/10.1177/001979399304600403). The firms applied for these grants, and they were distributed using a first-come, first-served rule. The authors argue that this is essentially as good as random once you condition on some controls.

Comment: The point of all this is not to dredge up old papers on OJT or debate whether the assumption is credible, but to add that there are also considerations about how the data were generated that also inform which estimator is appropriate.